# How to use set<int>

Tags: c++

I have been told to store {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} int a vector of type set. I have tried the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Set
{
    private:
    vector< set<int> > mySet;


    public:

        Set() : mySet(5) { }

        void setMySet()
        {
            mySet[0].emplace({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
        }

        void getFirstElemet()
        {
            cout << mySet[0].size() ;
        }

};


int main()
{
    Set testme;
    testme.getFirstElemet();
}
```

The error I get is this

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set::emplace()’
>       mySet[0].emplace({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Ron how to fix the error ?

Comment: Did you read documentation of standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), notably  of [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) and [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) ? Be also aware of the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)...

Comment: @scohe001 thanks, I added it. But, it still shows the same mistake

Comment: @George Thanks, but it still displays the same error

Comment: @scohe001 yup, I am using g++ -std=c++11

Comment: Fyi, `setMySet` isn't even called. So I would not expect much from it regardless.

Comment: `mySet.emplace_back(std::set<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});` even.

Comment: @SamJackson Did you follow another advice, which was, to read documentation of those classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `std::set::emplace` takes arguments to construct a *single* element of the set. So essentially what you've written is equivalent to `int i{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};` - that can't work.

You can instead use

```
for (auto i : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9})
    mySet[0].emplace(i);
```

or the even better version

```
mySet[0].insert({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9})
```

mentioned by Snps in the comment.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works. But how can I print them ?

Comment: @SamJackson Print all numbers in the set? `for(auto i : mySet[0]) std::cout << i << '\n';`

Comment: Or even `mySet[0].insert({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9})`. `std::set::insert` is faster as it can precalculate allocation cost (reserve).

Comment: Thanks again. I really appreciate it. It works. I got it now. I have last question and I will be grateful if you can answer it, Is is correct to think of sets like arrays ? I mean I can't understand sets as I haven't seen it before.

Comment: @SamJackson A set is _**not**_ like an array. Unlike an array, `std::set` will only contain unique values and it is ordered. Memory wise, `std::set` is also not stored contiguously.

Comment: @Snps Thanks so much for the reply. I saw it in maths but I didn't think it is the same 'set'

Comment: C++ `std::set`-s are always finite (and are mutable data structures). In math you have infinite sets which don't change. So it is not exactly the same thing.